# Change background color on mouseover and remove it after mouseout

Tags: jquery, mouse, mouseover, mouseout

I have table which class is `forum`. My jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.forum').bind("mouseover", function(){
            var color  = $(this).css("background-color");

            $(this).css("background", "#380606");

            $(this).bind("mouseout", function(){
                $(this).css("background", color);
            })    
        })    
    })
</script>
```

It perfectly works, but is it possible to do it in more efficient way without `var color  = $(this).css("background-color");`. Just after `mouseout` leave the previous background-color and remove `#380606`? Thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason you need it in JQuery out of interest? As this is the type of thing CSS is used for, so one of the answers below would be ideal in most situations.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If you don't care about IE ≤6, you could use pure CSS ...

```
.forum:hover { background-color: #380606; }
```

```css
.forum { color: white; }
.forum:hover { background-color: #380606 !important; }
/* we use !important here to override specificity. see http://stackoverflow.com/q/5805040/ */

#blue { background-color: blue; }
```

```html
<meta charset=utf-8>

<p class="forum" style="background-color:red;">Red</p>
<p class="forum" style="background:green;">Green</p>
<p class="forum" id="blue">Blue</p>
```

---

With jQuery, usually it is better to create a specific class for this style:

```
.forum_hover { background-color: #380606; }
```

and then apply the class on mouseover, and remove it on mouseout.

```
$('.forum').hover(function(){$(this).toggleClass('forum_hover');});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.forum').hover(function(){$(this).toggleClass('forum_hover');});
});
```

```css
.forum_hover { background-color: #380606 !important; }

.forum { color: white; }
#blue { background-color: blue; }
```

```html
<meta charset=utf-8>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="forum" style="background-color:red;">Red</p>
<p class="forum" style="background:green;">Green</p>
<p class="forum" id="blue">Blue</p>
```

---

If you must not modify the class, you could save the original background color in `.data()`:

```
  $('.forum').data('bgcolor', '#380606').hover(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var newBgc = $this.data('bgcolor');
    $this.data('bgcolor', $this.css('background-color')).css('background-color', newBgc);
  });
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.forum').data('bgcolor', '#380606').hover(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var newBgc = $this.data('bgcolor');
    $this.data('bgcolor', $this.css('background-color')).css('background-color', newBgc);
  });
});
```

```css
.forum { color: white; }
#blue { background-color: blue; }
```

```html
<meta charset=utf-8>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="forum" style="background-color:red;">Red</p>
<p class="forum" style="background:green;">Green</p>
<p class="forum" id="blue">Blue</p>
```

or

```
  $('.forum').hover(
    function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.data('bgcolor', $this.css('background-color')).css('background-color', '#380606');
    },
    function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.css('background-color', $this.data('bgcolor'));
    }
  );
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.forum').hover(
    function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.data('bgcolor', $this.css('background-color')).css('background-color', '#380606');
    },
    function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.css('background-color', $this.data('bgcolor'));
    }
  );    
});
```

```css
.forum { color: white; }
#blue { background-color: blue; }
```

```html
<meta charset=utf-8>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="forum" style="background-color:red;">Red</p>
<p class="forum" style="background:green;">Green</p>
<p class="forum" id="blue">Blue</p>
```

Comment: No, I need this done in Jquery actually, it is just a one piece of code.

Answer (score 20):

Set the original background-color in you CSS file:

```
.forum{
    background-color:#f0f;
}​
```

You don't have to capture the original color in jQuery. Remember that jQuery will alter the style INLINE, so by setting the background-color to null you will get the same result.

```
$(function() {
    $(".forum").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).css('background-color', '#ff0')
    }, function() {
        $(this).css('background-color', '')
    });
});​
```

Comment: That is a great answer! and it works perfectly... Tested in firebugs

Comment: Thanks, appreciated! If you want, you can include the jquery.color plugin. Then you have the ability to change color with animation. e.g. $(this).animate({backgroundColor:'#ff0'},400);

Answer (score 8):

**Try this , its working and simple**

HTML

```
​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div class="forum">
        test
    </div>
</body>
</html>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var colorOrig=$(".forum").css('background-color');
    $(".forum").hover(
    function() {
        //mouse over
        $(this).css('background', '#ff0')
    }, function() {
        //mouse out
        $(this).css('background', colorOrig)
    });
});​
```

css
​

```
.forum{
    background:#f0f;
}​
```

live demo

http://jsfiddle.net/caBzg/

Comment: your variable colorOrig will return null as the css property "background" selector is unreadable by jQuery... use "background-color" or "backgroundColor" instead

Answer (score 3):

This should be set directly in the CSS.

```
.forum {background-color: #123456}
.forum:hover {background-color: #380606}
```

If you are worried about the fact the IE6 will not accept hover over elements which are not links, you can use the [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) event of jQuery for compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div id="id">
</div>
<div id="hiddenDiv" style="display:none;"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#id').hover(function(){
    $("#hiddenDiv").css('display','block');
  },
  function(){
    $("#hiddenDiv").css('display','none');
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

**After lot of struggle finally got it working. ( Perfectly tested)**

The below example will also support the fact that color of already clicked button should not be changes

JQuery Code

```
var flag = 0; // Flag is to check if you are hovering on already clicked item

$("a").click(function() {
    $('a').removeClass("YourColorClass");
    $(this).addClass("YourColorClass");
    flag=1;
}); 

$("a").mouseover(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("YourColorClass")) {
        flag=1;
    }
    else{
        $(this).addClass("YourColorClass");
    };
});

$("a").mouseout(function() {
    if (flag == 0) {
        $(this).removeClass("YourColorClass");
    }
    else{
        flag = 0;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $( "td" ).on({
    "click": clicked,
    "mouseover": hovered,
    "mouseout": mouseout
});

var flag=0;

function hovered(){
  $(this).css("background", "#380606");
}

function mouseout(){
  if (flag == 0){
  $(this).css("background", "#ffffff");
} else {
  flag=0;
}
}

function clicked(){
  $(this).css("background","#000000");
  flag=1;
}
})
```