# syntaxhighlighter how to change the color of comment

Tags: syntaxhighlighter

I am new to using syntaxhighlighter. I am using there latest version 3.0.83. Can some one help how to customize the color of comments, header, etc ?

I am using  < pre class="brush: c"> for coding style.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to override the CSS rules for comments, but they're marked as `!important` so you have to do a little extra work.

Open your `shBrushCpp.js` file. Down towards the bottom there's a set of regular expression rules paired with a `css` property. Those values correspond to class names in `shThemeDefault.css` (or whatever theme you're using).

Copy your theme file to something like `shThemeCustom.css` or whatever you want. Include this file on your page instead of the original theme. From here, you can change whatever you want. Just reference the CSS rules from the brush file against your custom theme to know what needs to be changed.

Comment: I've got a problem. I don't have access to any custom css files that I know of, as I [followed this installation here](http://beendaved.blogspot.com/2015/03/working-with-syntax-highlighter-in.html), and am using Alex Gorbatchev's online hostings (ex: http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/styles/shThemeDefault.css, http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushCpp.js, etc, per the instructions above), so how can I do this in my case? Note: [my website](http://www.electricrcaircraftguy.com/) is a Google Blogger blog.

Comment: I just added [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40179189/4561887). Took me several hours but I got it all figured out.

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't have full control over the .css or .js files, as is my case (since I followed [these instructions here](http://beendaved.blogspot.com/2015/03/working-with-syntax-highlighter-in.html) and am using [Alex Gorbatchev's hosted files instead](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/hosting.html)), there is still [a way to override the `!important` parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178673/how-to-override-important).

You can customize any of the settings shown here (http://agorbatchev.typepad.com/pub/sh/3_0_83/styles/shThemeDefault.css), for example, as follows:

With the default theme, this HTML...

```
<pre class="brush:cpp" title="test code">
int myFunc()
{
  //do something
  return 1;
}
</pre>
```

...yields this result:

[image]

Looking here (http://agorbatchev.typepad.com/pub/sh/3_0_83/styles/shThemeDefault.css), I can see the parameters I am currently using. For example, it contains:

```
.syntaxhighlighter {
  background-color: white !important;
}
.syntaxhighlighter .line.alt1 {
  background-color: white !important;
}
.syntaxhighlighter .line.alt2 {
  background-color: white !important;
}
...
.syntaxhighlighter .comments, .syntaxhighlighter .comments a {
  color: #008200 !important;
}
```

In order from top to bottom, as shown just above, my header background color is white and my alternating code lines 1 and 2 are both white. Comments are green (`#008200`). Let's change all of that. Add the following code to your blogger template, at the very end of your header, just above `</head>`:

```
<style type='text/css'>
  .syntaxhighlighter {
    max-height: 550px;
    background-color: #ff0000 !important;
    overflow-y: auto !important;
    overflow-x: auto !important;
  }
  .syntaxhighlighter .line.alt1 {
    background-color: #99ff99 !important;
  }
  .syntaxhighlighter .line.alt2 {
    background-color: #99ff99 !important;
  }
  .syntaxhighlighter .comments, .syntaxhighlighter .comments a {
    color: #000082 !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
  }
</style>
```

Now, I have set my `max-height`to 550 pixels (make a really long code block and you'll see it constrained to this height now, with a vertical slider to see it all), my header background color is red (`#ff0000`), my code background color (both alternating lines) is light green (`#99ff99`), and my comments are blue (`#000082`) and **bold**. Follow this format to customize anything you see in your .css theme file--example, for me, here: http://agorbatchev.typepad.com/pub/sh/3_0_83/styles/shThemeDefault.css.

Here is my final result--very different from the default look above:

[image]

Note that the `font-weight` parameter I set is simply a CSS styling you can apply. Many other options exist. See here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_weight.asp.