# Display none ! important need to override by using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

Anyone who is knowing how to override the below mentioned css by using jQuery ?

```
 .actionButton.single-pet
        {
            display: none !important;
        }
```

It won't work for  this : `$('.actionButton.single-pet').show();`

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

Comment: Does `.actionButton.single-pet` class has more css properties rather than `display: none !important;` ?

Comment: @Mr_Green Nope,That is the only property.But 'actionButton' class has lot of properties.That's why I have introduced 'single-pet' class and override the display behavior of 'actionButton'.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

```
$('.actionButton.single-pet').attr("style", "display: inline !important");
```

Sets CSS to `display: inline !important;`. `display: inline` is the default property for `display`. You need `!important` again to override the previous `!important`.

Note that `!important` shouldn't be used often. Read the accepted answer at [How to override !important?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11178673) for more details.

UPDATE: We can't use `.css()` here as it does not support `!important`. http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11173 for more details; appears to be a bug.

Comment: Noted, using another method. Also, I would like to know why my answer is downvoted. Thanks.

Comment: maybe because your post is not an answer to OP's question.

Comment: @Mr_Green hmm, I don't see why it isn't an answer to the OP's question.

Comment: yeah sorry I overlooked

Comment: @MathijsFlietstra there were some errors in your fiddle. I updated it. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bbSNM/2/). :)

Comment: Yes I realised just then, but the answer does work :) thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('.actionButton.single-pet').removeClass('single-pet');
```

Or just:

```
$('.actionButton.single-pet').addClass('single-pet-shown');
```

With CSS:

```
.actionButton.single-pet-shown {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Comment: Without the rest of his CSS and markup, this is a pure guess, not an educated answer.

Comment: The OP might not want `.single-pet` to be removed.

Comment: @Mr_Green No, it does not. It does not **override** the css property, it simply removes it. Please read the OP question again.

Comment: @wei2912 ya, but he still could apply all other CSS rules relative to .single-pet class and use a new class .single-pet-shown without display:none !important rule.

Comment: What if `.single-pet` also has some other properties elsewhere in the stylesheet and they are crucial to the document's layout?

Comment: @DevlshOne is that hard to toggle between classes? BTW, he could just add a new class which would override the display rule of previous class

Comment: @A.Wolff the point here is to override "display: none !important;" such that `.single-pet` is shown. Nothing else should be modified.

Comment: @wei2912 so you cannot. Is this the answer OP is looking for?

Comment: @DevlshOne what if it doesn't? let just leave this to OP to decide. or if someone have better alternative then they will post it as answer.

Comment: @A.Wolff you can override `!important` by creating another rule with `!important`, but is further on in the CSS stylesheet. According to standard CSS rules, that should override.

Comment: @wei2912 I write that because you said: 'Nothing else should be modified.' so now i'm confused...

Comment: @A.Wolff ah, sorry for the confusion.