# How to override !important when switching from % to px

Tags: css

I have been forced to work with some very poorly written CSS and I am not allowed to change it, only override its settings.

The issue is that it has something like this:

```
.some_div{ width: 10% !important; }
```

However, I need it to do the width in pixels, not percentage. SO, when I try to do the following:

```
.some_div{ width: 146px; }
```

There is no change. Even if I add an '!important'.

Does anyone know a good trick to override the % setting so I can use PX?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178673/how-to-override-important

Comment: As long as the second rule (`px`) appears after the first one (10% `!important`) then if you add important to the second rule, it will work - http://jsfiddle.net/nQVCN/

Comment: KayakDave, please actually read the question. YOu will see it is OBVIOUSLY not the same question.

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle Adam. It appears there is some other factor causing this issue.

Comment: @LeeLoftiss Sorry I wasn't clearer- check the first answer (Overriding the !important modifier - Simply add another CSS rule with !important ...) in the link and I think you'll see the connection with the answer that I was trying to point you at.  And it's connection to the answer that ultimately and happily worked out for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another rule with that is more specific with `!important` or add your rule after the existing rule. The last one will win.

```
.some_div{ width: 146px !important; }
```

Comment: I must have some other error then because I tried this and it didn't work. But a Fiddle posted by Adam and your comments make it clear it should be working.

Comment: @LeeLoftiss try making your rule more specific. You can't always depend on having your CSS load after the old rule.

Comment: By 'more specific', are you saying something like #parent_div .some_div{} ?

Comment: Yes, that should do, also .some_other_class .some_div should also work.