# Custom CSS is not being applied thoroughly

Tags: css

I am currently designing a theme but my CSS styles are not being applied throughout the entire site.

It was suggested that my CSS lacks specificity, but  the issue isn't that I can't override the default styles; the issue is that it's not using my custom style sheet. That can be proven because my styles work on certain pages.

I'm not sure what's causing the problem or how to fix it.

```
#Head {
background: #D6AD33;
padding: 0px;
}
/*Panels/Sidebars*/
.Box {
 border-radius: 1px;
 -moz-border-radius: 1px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
 background:    #FFA366;
 color: #888;
 padding: 6px 10px;
 margin: 0 0 10px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #999;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #999;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #999;  
}
.Box h4 {
 font-size: 110%;
 color: #FF6600;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0 0 1px;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code here? It's hard to help without seeing it.

Comment: "*That can be proven because my styles work on certain pages*". That doesn't prove anything, maybe your styles are applied always but sometimes overridden with more specific styles. The only way to see what's happening: **learn to debug**

Comment: Where are these "default styles" coming from? Is it possible they're using `!important`s?

Comment: @Oriol I have learned. The only stylistic change I made was to hexadecimal value for the background, everything else is the same.

Comment: @pdoherty926 When I started using this open source, a theme called "2011Compatibility" was enabled. So, the default styles are coming from their custom CSS. I believe they using `!important`

Comment: Here's the link for the files [2011Compatibility](https://github.com/vanillaforums/Garden/tree/master/themes/2011Compatibility)

Comment: If that's the case, refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11178731/382982) answer.