# Reduce textbox height

Tags: html, css

I have input type TEXT in my form, i want to reduce the HEIGHT, i have tried many things, but seems like whatever I do it does not work, I tried with line-height, margin etc. below is something i have.

```
  .txtboxItem{
    height: 1em;
    font-size:8px;
    }
```

and here is  my markup

```
<input class="txtboxItem" type="text" id="txt_emailAddress" />
```

please note, width works fine, font looks small in my textbox, but why height of textbox is NOT reducing?

EDIT: I think my external file has input property with "!", anyway I can override it in my local html file?

Comment: Have you tried changing em to px ?

Comment: have you tried to add `!important` to the height?

Comment: yes i did, but to to avail.

Comment: I think `!important` could normally override another attribute, but you have to make sure when both of them have `!important`, you have to put your `.txtboxItem` declaration after the external one to be in effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its working for me using px...

```
input{height:5px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mvNDh/

edit:
I've used your code and its working in the same jsfiddle...
http://jsfiddle.net/mvNDh/

Comment: its just not working, what could be the issue? where should I look in my HTML?

Comment: try changing 1em to .5em

Comment: no effect, it works fine in fiddle, anyway to debug it? seems like my class is NOT overriding the code written by somebody else in a external css/bootstrap template.

Comment: hmm...yes. Try putting it inline-  <input style="height:.5em" ... That should over ride anything else. Also, open in google inspector (right click in chrome, click inspect element)  to set the values directly for testing.

Comment: this is bothering me too much...even <input style="height:.5em" type="text" id="txt_emailAddress" /> did not work.

Comment: No, I guess too much OCD. lol. I think problem is some external css file has "!" with input type text, anyway to override the "!" stuff?

Comment: right - I'm not sure. I think you should start a new thread with that question. But a quick search says you can't override it.

Comment: I did find this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178673/how-to-override-important try useing ! in your css - sounds like this will override the previously loaded css important.

Answer (score 0):

Use px instead of em, as em in most browsers is generally equal to about 16px unless the user has changed their default value.

```
height:8px;
```

Try remove any padding or margins

```
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
```

Comment: it works just fine in fiddle, but in my web application textbox goes UP in height just fine, however it would not go down in height.

Comment: You could try see if there is any padding and remove it. Note my updates