# How can I preserve my colors when printing when using Bootstrap (which resets them to #000)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

how can I preserve my colors when printing (to pdf in my case) when using bootstrap?

Bootstrap is using

```
@media print {  
   * {    
     color: #000 !important; 
   }
}
```

Is there anything I can put AFTER this in my css that would return the color behavior to normal?

I tried

```
@media print {
  * {
    color: inherit !important;
  }
}
```

and

```
@media print {
  * {
    color: auto !important;
  }
}
```

Without success.

Comment: i don't suppose deleting the bootstrap definition for print is possible/removing **!important** from bootstrap definition?

Comment: I could remove it, and that seems to be the only way I can think. But I'd rather not do this so I can easily stay up to date with bootstrap releases.

Comment: Just came across this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178673/how-to-override-important I think it pretty much says 'the last important wins' and/or 'place css inline'

Comment: Does your CSS come AFTER the Bootstrap CSS? If so, then `color: inherit` should work.

Comment: Yes the css IS after bootstrap

Comment: @pixelearth: Did you found solution to this?