# how to override the inline css having !important declaration

Tags: html, css

How to override the inline css having !important property.
I have tried the following link also [How to override !important?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178673/how-to-override-important)
but this is not helping.

```
<head>
ul{
color:yellow !important;//from here i want to overrride the inline css**
}
</head>

<body>
<div id="something">
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td>
     <ul>
       <li style="color:#fff !important"></li> // i want to oveeride this inline css
     </ul>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to add strength of specificity without changing the specificity of specificity (ie reducing the scope of matched elements) is to add `:nth-child( n )` to the selector.

```css
ul:nth-child( n ) {
  color: yellow !important;
}
```

```html
<ul style="color: red !important">
  <li>
    Am I red?
  </li>
</ul>
```

The reason `:nth-child( n )` is especially good for this is that it will never disqualify the selector, because all elements match `:nth-child( n )`. It can also be stacked indefinitely:

```css
:nth-child( n ):nth-child( n ):nth-child( n ){
  color: red;
}

:nth-child( n ):nth-child( n ){
  color: blue;
}

:nth-child( n ){
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
nth-child will stack any number of times!
```

Comment: Of course you will not be able to overwrite `style="color: red !important"` with **any** of your selectors.

Comment: Haha you're utterly right.

Comment: This is a good article with selectors weights: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/