# Can't Overwrite CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am implementing Snipcart on my site on this page

http://www.system-training.com/store/

In the cart (click to buy)

I am attempting to overwrite the CSS with this style-sheet, but it's not working.

http://www.system-training.com/css/snipcart-overwrite.css

Any ideas?

Comment: May be you are looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178673/how-to-override-important)

Comment: Please try to include the relevant code snippets within the question text. Enough to demonstrate the issue. As the site you're working on is bound to change, this question becomes rather useless once it does. We prefer that questions are capable of helping others beyond the one asking. [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: if i look at your css and then look up your selectors in the html they are nowhere to be found (`snipcart-next` does not exist, same for `a.snipcart-finalize` and `a.snipcart-mainaction`, at least in the page you've linked).

Answer (score 1):

Use right-click "Inspect element" in Chrome (or equivalent in other browsers) and hover over the element that is not inheriting styles properly. It will illustrate where the styles causing conflict are.