# How to change a !important css property?

Tags: css

I have a stylesheet which has the following property,

```
.primary-nav .suppa_rwd_button, .primary-nav .suppa_rwd_button span{
    color:#FFFFFF!important;   
}
```

I can't edit the stylesheet. How do I change the property to

```
color:#000000!important;
```

I tried to write the following code in another stylesheet,

```
.primary-nav .suppa_rwd_button, .primary-nav .suppa_rwd_button span{
    color:#000000!important;   
}
```

but it did not work. Please guide. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178673/how-to-override-important

Comment: Can you change your HTML?

Comment: @ManojKumar: Yes. I can change the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

In order to override an `!important` rule you have to put a same specific rule after the previous one or to increase specificity of new rule as:

```
nav.primary-nav li.suppa_rwd_button, nav.primary-nav li.suppa_rwd_button span{
    color:#000000!important;   
}
```

* suppose that `.primary-nav` is a `nav` element and `.suppa_rwd_button` a `li` element, you could change them due to your markup.

In both cases you have to also use `!important` in your new rule.

Reference: [MDN - Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Answer (score 0):

Other than Emmanuel's answer which talks about this: [**CSS Specificity**](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/), You can *also* try using two approaches:

**Change order of stylesheet**

Make sure your other stylesheet order is higher than the current version. That is include the new stylesheet link after the stylesheet which is to be overridden

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css"> <!-- Styles that will overwrite -->
```

---

**Inline HTML**

If you can change your HTML, you can use this:

```
<span style="color: #000000 !important;">
```

`!important` in inline style will have higher priority than in other types of styles.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using:

```
.primary-nav .suppa_rwd_button span{
color:#000000!important;   
}
```

Other way could be using JavaScript:

Override using JavaScript

```
$('.mytable td').attr('style', 'display: none !important');
```

Cheers!