# CSS disable bootstrap box-sizing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

by default bootstrap has `box-sizing` and ruined my layout and i can not disable that :

```
#menu_items {
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box !important;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box !important;
    box-sizing: content-box !important;
    width: auto;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

this tip dont work and after delete `box-sizing` layout work fine

Quastion:

how to disable this feature on my own layout and disable `in-herit`

Comment: What is your question? There is none currently.

Comment: If it ruined your layout, it's more likely that your layout was wrong. That setting is there for a reason.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

BootStrap sets border-box on all elements by default:

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

To override this, simply ensure your custom CSS file is referenced AFTER BootStrap in your site and set it back to the default `content-box` :

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
          box-sizing: content-box;
}
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
          box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Check this fiddle out: https://jsfiddle.net/movs6gw0/1/

I added the BootStrap CSS file as a resource and if you inspect the content I've placed in the `p` tags, you'll notice that BootStrap's border-box styling on `*` (all) elements has been overriden by what I've placed above.

CSS is "Cascading", meaning whatever style you declare can be overriden by the same style declaration further down the CSS file / document. No need to use `!important` unless absolutely crucial, in my opinion that goes against the philosophy of CSS.

Take the following example: https://jsfiddle.net/av4jbyt6/

```
<p>
  Test content
</p>
```

CSS:

```
p {
  color: white;
}
p {
  color: red;
}
```

Both styles above reference the same element (`p`), but the final style overrides the one before because it is further down the chain...

Comment: Thank you very much sir. i edit `*` to `#menu_items li {} #menu_items li:before, #menu_items li:after {}` solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

Regarding to this post you can overwrite `!important` rules by adding a class to your element and using a higher specified selector.

[How to override !important?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178673/how-to-override-important)

In your case, something like `.menu_items.no-box-sizing` could do the trick.

**EDIT:** I guess adding a rule with `!important` **after** the one Bootstrap defined, would do the trick as well.