# How can I override !important inline css?

Tags: html, css

I'm editing a page and **I can't** change the html, only the css, but I need to change a background-image that is declared inline with !important.
I've already tried to declare background-image: none !important; or change bg position until it disappear and then declare the new bg image on :before pseudo-element, but it doesn't work.
Is there any way to do this WITHOUT change the html?
Here's the code:

```
<ul class="list-inline">
    <li>
       <a href="http://www.facebook.com/portoseguro" target="_blank">
         <span class="gIconSocial fb" style="background: url('https://cliente.portoseguro.com.br/static-files/Institucional/Icones/facebook_off.png') no-repeat !important;">Facebook</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

(I can't use javascript too, only css)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to override !important?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178673/how-to-override-important)

Comment: It's not a duplicate, you can override !important that is in css-file by adding another after that but this is inline css. I think this can't be done. If you can add css why can't you add javascript?

Comment: If you have JavaScript you can change it using that, otherwise you're out of luck. Hackerman's suggestion is not true, it's about overriding a rule in a CSS file, which can be done by adding one with higher specificity, but for inline styles, that can't be done. That is probably why they added it like this: to make really really sure no-one tempers with it.

Comment: Link:-https://css-tricks.com/override-inline-styles-with-css/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the background image by adding the CSS `background-size: 0;` and try to put a background image to `ul.list-inline > li > a[target=_blank]`

### EDIT :

rather use `ul.list-inline > li > a[target]` or it wont work

Answer (score 2):

The browser gives the priority to the inline style. And, since this is with `!important` property you have to edit the HTML to get rid of this if you wanna do this with CSS only.

I recommend you to read more about **Specificity** on applying styles