# Change an !important property using JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I've already got the text color of a select box set with an `!important` value and am struggling to change it again using jQuery.

```
<div class="halio-form-container">
    ...
    <select class="form-control" id="HalioDirection" name="halio_direction">
        <option selected="" disabled="">Direction...</option>
        <option value="one_way">One Way</option>
        <option value="return">Return</option>      
    </select>
    ...
</div>

.halio-form-container select {
    color: #B0A9A9 !important;
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you make a JS fiddle? Hard to understand. What jQuery action you perform to change the color of select box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to not use the `!important` at all and refactor your css (and possibly markup) such that proper selector [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) allows you to do what you need without `!important`.

That being said, general way to override an `!important` is to add another CSS rule with `!important` with either a higher specificity, or same specificity but defined at a later point. This works because in a specificity tie, the last rule defined wins.

Related question: [How to override !important](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178673/how-to-override-important)

---

Since we need to use JS/jQuery and not CSS, there are three possible solutions:

#### 1. Add an inline !important rule

We can beat `!important` with a more-specific rule by adding an inline `!important` rule.

The reason this works is because inline styles always overwrite any styles in external stylesheets, and thus can be thought of as having the highest specificity.

```js
var currentStyle = $('#test').attr('style') || '';
$('#test').attr('style', currentStyle + ' color:red !important');
```

```css
#test {
  color: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  This text is RED, not BLUE
</div>
```

#### 2. Add a new style element

We can beat `!important` with a later-defined-equally-specific `!important` rule by creating another stylesheet containing this rule and appending it to `<head>`.

```js
$('<style>#test { color:red !important; }</style>').appendTo('head');
```

```css
#test {
  color: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  This text is RED, not BLUE
</div>
```

#### 3. Append to last style element

Basically another version of `2.` where, instead of creating a new style, we append our new rule to the end of the last style:

```js
var lastStyle = $('style').last();
lastStyle.html(lastStyle.html() + '\n#test { color:red !important; }');
```

```css
#test {
  color: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  This text is RED, not BLUE
</div>
```

Additional resources:

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception)