# How to change display style css

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Hi I've a wordpress site and i need to modify the highlighted code to "display=flex" insted of "display=none".
But i am not able to to this because is element.style..please help me.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoTvS.jpg

```
              .fep-message-content .fep-message-content-5 .fep-message- 
              content-own .fep-message-content-admin .fep-hide-if-js{

                    display:flex !important;

               }
```

this is an accordion of front-end-pm plugin for wordpress and it is displayed none when closed and displayed block when opened. i would have it permaopened.

Is possible to change the highligthed code?
Thank you for helping. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to override !important?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178673/how-to-override-important)

Comment: * {font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace}

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that there's a javascript hiding that element after the page is loaded. So no matter what you tell the page to load, it gets altered after. I would search the theme or plugin javascripts for "fep-hide-if-js".

Comment: Thank you , the plugin i'm using is front end pm for wp, and this is an accordion that is displayed none when closed and displayed block when opened. i would have it permaopened.