# CSS override !important

Tags: html, css

I am trying to customize the css of my website but the default theme has !important property next to color code which I am not able to override.

**By Default:**

```css
body.theme-whyte .main-wrapper #header .main-nav .content .menu-block-wrapper > ul > li.expanded:hover > .nolink,
body.theme-whyte .main-wrapper #header .main-nav .content .menu-block-wrapper > ul > li.expanded:hover > .nolink::after {
  color: #404040 !important;
}
```

**Changes I would like to make:**

```css
body.theme-whyte .main-wrapper #header .main-nav .content .menu-block-wrapper > ul > li.expanded:hover > .nolink,
body.theme-whyte .main-wrapper #header .main-nav .content .menu-block-wrapper > ul > li.expanded:hover > .nolink::after {
  color: #a03021 !important;
}
```

I am not able to override !important tag. I am a bit new to CSS. Can someone please help me out with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try loading the custom css file which has your changes before the theme css?

Comment: There is just an option of CSS Editor where I am inputting the custom css code. I cannot upload the custom css file.

Comment: there was a question as your same topic..check this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178673/how-to-override-important

Answer (score 0):

Order of priority in CSS:

1) In-Line CSS

2) Embedded CSS

3) External CSS

The same will work even if the tags are `!important`.

[Example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/types-of-css-cascading-style-sheet/)

If your changes are from stylesheets which are all external, just put the stylesheet with the desired style in, **after** the one you wish to replace.