# How to overrule !important css rule from bootstrap

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, angular-animations

I'm trying to set a css style `display: none;` with angular animations to an element that already has a bootstrap class `.d-block`, which sets display as `.d-block { display: block!important;}`.
How can I overrule the `.d-block` class ?

```
  trigger('fade', [
    state('hidden', style({
      opacity: 0,
      display: 'none'
    })),
    state('show', style({
      opacity: 1,
      display: 'block'
    })),
    transition('hidden => show', [
      animate('1s')
    ]),
    transition('show => hidden', [
      animate('1s')
    ])
```

Comment: Have a google around `specificity` https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Comment: @Dominik i can't control the specificity of the css rule given by bootstrap, I can only set the class. which means I would have to be more specific with my css within the angular animation, which I don't know/think is possible.

Comment: Obviously. You can increase the specificity of the overriding rule which is what I tried to suggest. It is possible as all you need is a higher specificity via moving to style attribute, or adding a higher specificity selector or ... 100 more things

Comment: @Dominik i get what you we're suggesting, but my question is how can i do that, add higher specificity, with a css rule that is applied via angular animations ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178673/how-to-override-important

Comment: @Rajat thank you, but that doesn't answer my question if it's possible or not to give higher specificity to the css rule within angular animations. `display: 'none !important'` is not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found a way to add higher specificity within the angular animations css rule, so for the time being I removed `.d-block` and added `display: block` in my css file.

This way the normal css rule is overruled by the angular animations rule.