# How to increase priority without using !important?

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-specificity

How do I get rid of the `!important` tag in the following example?

```html
<html><head><style>

  .class1.class2::after {
    content: ".class1.class2";
  }
  .class3::after {
    content: ".class3" !important;
    /* how do we make this higher priority without "!important"? */
  }
  

td {padding-right: 20px;}

</style></head>
<body>

<table>
<tr><td>class1 class2</td><td><div class="class1 class2"></div></td></tr>
<tr><td>class1 class2 class3</td><td><div class="class1 class2 class3"></div></td></tr>
</table>

</body></html>
```

I am aware of 3 rule precedence mechanisms in CSS:

1. **Specificity**. The issue with the above example is that according to the browser's [specificity algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), `.class1.class2` is considered more "specific" than `.class3`. So specificity is not a good fit here, since the browser invents an illogical relationship between `.class1.class2` and `.class3`.
2. **Declaration order** appears not to work either: since specificity takes precedence over declaration order, it does not matter what order the rules are written in.
3. **!important**. But it is frowned upon (if you can educate me on *why* it's frowned upon, that might give us some insight).
   Can I avoid `!important` if I want `.class3` to take higher precedence in the example above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've already mentioned, it comes down to **Specificity**. You can modify your CSS to make the `.class3` entry more specific and add-on the original selector `.class1.class2.class3::after, .class3::after`.

`.class1.class2.class3` will override `.class1.class2` because the former contains the latter.

I think that `!important` is frowned upon purely because it's seen like a bit of a hack/workaround to force a particular style in the absence of properly formatted and written CSS.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .class1.class2::after {
      content: ".class1.class2";
    }
    
    .class1.class2.class3::after,
    .class3::after {
      content: ".class3";
    }
    
    td {
      padding-right: 20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>class1 class2</td>
      <td>
        <div class="class1 class2"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>class1 class2 class3</td>
      <td>
        <div class="class1 class2 class3"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, this approach seems to work well. The browser still finds the containment relation, even if I expand the first rule to, say, `.stuff1.stuff2,.stuff3,.stuff4::after,  .class1.class2::after, .stuff5.stuff6,.stuff7,.stuff8::after`. And it's pretty readable - seeing a selector and a more specific one on the same rule just says "Here's how I want to resolve this specific ambiguity."

Answer (score 2):

The *important flag* (`!important`) is "frowned upon" by some because it is often used as a substitute for good coding practices.

It can be seen as encouraging sloppy code because, in the end, *"we can just use `!important`"*.

Eventually, however, this practice results in problems like these: [How to override !important?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11178673/3597276)

But if you're already writing good quality code, or you're trying to override code that is beyond your control (e.g., WordPress), or you need to make a change in one page, but not the whole site, then the important flag can be a handy tool.

Bottom line, there's nothing wrong with `!important` when used properly. It exists for a reason.

Comment: Thank you. This addresses the second part of my question. Needless `!important`s making the code sloppy makes sense... and I also like your examples of where `!important` might be good practice after all. (Thankfully, per Jordan's answer, the simple example I gave is not one of those occasions. Before I understood Jordan's answer, however, `!important` seemed to me like a more urgent necessity).