# Media Query CSS important

Tags: css, media

Making responsive website,

I wrote this, it doesn't work.

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    #nav { display:block; }
}
```

but, I wrote this, it works!

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    #nav { display:block !important; }
}
```

Why? :(

Comment: Perhaps there's a selector somewhere which has a higher priority. read about [CSS specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/).

Answer (score 0):

Check your css code , something with higher specificity is changing your #nav element.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little concept:

`!important` after the style attribute gives high priority to that style. That is why your css is working then.
`!important` override the existing stylesheet attribute defined in same context.

Answer (score 0):

`!important` will override any inline style, or more specific style that may be taking precedence on your page.

For example, you can override the style on this element...

```
<div style='background-color:white'></div>
```

by adding this in your stylesheet...

```
div { background-color: black !important }
```

But!, if you add `!important` to the inline style, it will then take precedence, for example...

```
<div style='background-color:white !important'></div>
```

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5805204/1167867) is a good stackoverflow answer explaining the concept in a bit more detail.