# Which CSS selector is stronger?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Which selector is stronger?

```
#nav li.current
```

or

```
div #nav li
```

and second

```
a.test
```

or

```
.test .test
```

What is the answer?

Comment: The first is `1,1,1` whereas the second is `1,0,2`, so the first is stronger. In the second part, you have `1,1` vs. `2,0`, making the second one stronger.

Comment: A better question to ask is how to determine selector strength, then you can calculate it on your own.

Comment: Try it for yourself using the Specificity Calculator http://specificity.keegan.st/

Comment: @Kolink what are those ones, twos and zero and how to calculate them?

Comment: IDs, classes, tags. That is the order of specificity. If a selector has more IDs, it wins. If they have the same, check the number of classes. If they have the same too, check the number of tags.

Comment: For a more detailed understanding than can be easily given here you may find http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/ helpful.

Comment: CSS Specificity Wars
 http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html

Comment: Ironically these are all poor selectors that professionals would avoid.

Comment: The question has already been answered, but I question the usefulness of these questions. There is never a reason to use `div #nav li`; just use `#nav li`. Also, `nav` is a tag now, so the use of `#nav` is questionable at best. If you find yourself needing `#nav li.current`, your html is probably poorly written, you'd be more likely to just use `#nav .current`.

Comment: @Llepwryd there's nothing wrong with naming an ID "nav". After all, that may be a `nav` element anyway. `<nav id="nav">...</nav>`. Equally, the "current" class may apply to elements of different types. The `li` selector would specifically select `li` elements with that class.

Comment: @Llepwryd A page can have multiple `nav` elements.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I realize that you can use the id `#nav` with no problems, but it seems like bad practice. I wouldn't advise using ids like `#div` or `#ul` either.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity):

> A selector's specificity is calculated as follows:
>
> - count the number of ID selectors in the selector (= a)
> - count the number of class selectors, attributes selectors, and pseudo-classes in the selector (= b)
> - count the number of type selectors and pseudo-elements in the selector (= c)
> - ignore the universal selector
>
> Selectors inside the negation pseudo-class are counted like any other, but the negation itself does not count as a pseudo-class.
>
> Concatenating the three numbers a-b-c (in a number system with a large base) gives the specificity.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> *               /* a=0 b=0 c=0 -> specificity =   0 */
> LI              /* a=0 b=0 c=1 -> specificity =   1 */
> UL LI           /* a=0 b=0 c=2 -> specificity =   2 */
> UL OL+LI        /* a=0 b=0 c=3 -> specificity =   3 */
> H1 + *[REL=up]  /* a=0 b=1 c=1 -> specificity =  11 */
> UL OL LI.red    /* a=0 b=1 c=3 -> specificity =  13 */
> LI.red.level    /* a=0 b=2 c=1 -> specificity =  21 */
> #x34y           /* a=1 b=0 c=0 -> specificity = 100 */
> #s12:not(FOO)   /* a=1 b=0 c=1 -> specificity = 101 */
> ```

Comment: Although this does not directly answer the OP's question, it provides all the tools needed for them to understand and answer themselves. Upvoted.

Comment: @pwdst I would say that that is better than directly answering the question

Comment: @pwdst Teach a man to fish...

Comment: @BillyMathews As it happens I agree completely, I was not criticising the answer in any way, simply saying that I thought this was the right approach to take. I thought that was clear in the comment, sorry if that was not the case.

Comment: @pwdst Ahhh, I see. I think it was the 'although' that threw me off.

Answer (score 10):

You can follow the following rules to calculate selectors as points.

> A tag selector is worth 1 point.
>
> A class selector is worth 10 points.
>
> An ID selector is worth 100 points.
>
> An inline style is worth 1,000 points.

`#nav li.current` = 100 + 1+10 = 111

`div #nav li` = 1 + 100 + 1 = 102

`a.test` = 1+10 = 11

`.test .test` = 10+10 = 20

Comment: Does it mean that you can overwrite inline style using `#foo #bar #baz #quux #foo2 #bar2 #baz2 #quux2 #foo3 #bar3 #baz3`?

Comment: It doesn't work http://jsfiddle.net/QNztu/. Inline style is not overwritten.

Comment: @jcubic AFAIK, css selection works from right to left. so if the first selection is ID then it will **not** look for the next selection because ID's are meant to be unique. So, the points for your above css selectors is just `100`.

Comment: @Mr_Green what about `#foo + #bar + #baz + #quux + #foo2 + #bar2 + #baz2 + #quux2 + #foo3 + #bar3 + #baz3` will it act the same? http://jsfiddle.net/QNztu/1/

Comment: @jcubic makes no sense. because **ID's are unique** it will make sense if you use tag names or class names instead of id's..

Comment: How much is `!important` worth?

Comment: The syntax of powers of 10 is essentially incorrect. You can never override a higher priority selector with many lower priority selector, even with > 10 of them - as jcubic just discovered. Other posters have used a comma-separated priority order, `a,b,c,d` or `0,1,0,2`, which makes this more clear.

Comment: @Mr_Green I put 102 nested classes into one selector and it don't overwrite the inline style http://jsfiddle.net/QNztu/3/

Comment: @Mr_Green: Specificity doesn't care how unique your IDs are. If you have 10 ids in a selector then the specificity is 10 ids.

Comment: @Patrick M: I seriously need to work on an answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809024/points-in-css-specificity).

Comment: @mikeTheLiar: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805040/important-in-css-specificity-points/5805204#5805204 although if you need to count `!important` in terms of precedence then it's 1 level more than an inline style, I guess? i.e. `!important` > inline style > id.

Comment: @BoltClock Wow, [Faust's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11934505/1146608) there is awesome, and really on par to what jcubic is getting at here. I would have guessed that all browsers used a base-infinity system. I disagree with the on-hold/off topic the question is now classified under - I would go along with closed/dupe.

Comment: @Patrick M: His answer, while completely correct, still implies that adding up points makes sense as a system for counting specificity, just with a strange base, which will likely lead to even further misconception especially among CSS authors. Granted, the spec says to implement it as a system with an arbitrarily large base, but of course, unless you implemented specificity in some complex data type you won't really be able to count in an infinitely large base.

Comment: @Patrick M: I guess what I intend to get at is there are much simpler, clearer, and most importantly more foolproof ways to count specificity, such as what you've mentioned earlier, than to rely on an implementation detail. (And I really should be putting all this in my answer.)