# :not(.MyClass) selector with important

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am adding a fiddle below that gives a visual on the matter I'm dealing with. While messing around with css selectors I've realized that the !important selector is very strong, until it meets its boss the :not selector.

```
div:not(.red){
    background-color:green !important;
    width:400px;
    height:50px
}
```

In my fiddle I declared an initial value of purple to all my backgrounds.
 I ordered the first one specifically to be red and the second one to be blue
 I then ordered all my backgrounds except red to be green. It did so!

Good so far

then I made a brown, and the another brown with a change of color to purple important. It changed both brown classes.

The confusing came about these two browns not turning green when I specifically demanded that all except red must be green! I said to myself, "the important selector sure it's strong!" Then I added an !important selector to my :not selector class for good measure. Given that the purple Important class is the bottom-est class, it will overwrite the Important on the Green and remain purple....OOOOHHHHH NOOOOOO!!!! They all (except red) turned GREEN!

What gives?

What is the true hierarchy and chain of command on css selectors?

Here is the [***FIDDLE***](http://jsfiddle.net/4Zj5C/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's basically because of the [selector's specificity.](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity)

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not),

> The specificity of the :not pseudo-class **is the specificity of its argument**. The :not pseudo-class does not add to the selector specificity, unlike other pseudo-classes.

Therefore the selector `div:not(.red)` is more specific than `.brown` regardless of order: [(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/7W8L7/)

```
div:not(.red) {
    background-color:green; /* Still applied */
}
.brown {
    background-color:purple; /* Overwritten - even though this appears last */
}
```

---

The same thing happens when we add in `!important` to the declaration: [(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/tQ42g/)

```
div:not(.red) {
    background-color:green!important; /* Still applied */
}
.brown {
    background-color:purple!important; /* Overwritten - even though this appears last */
}
```

---

However, if we increase the specificity of `.brown` by adding in the type, (`div.brown`), *its* background color will be applied. [(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/w2CDe/) Both selectors now have the same specificity, therefore the same thing occurs when `!important` is added to both. [(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/QLx4E/) At this point, it all comes down to order.

```
div:not(.red) {
    background-color:green;
}
div.brown {
    background-color:purple; /* This is applied now */
}                              /* ..even if both declarations have !important */
```

---

It's important to note that `!important` *doesn't* increase the specificity of a selector. Instead, it just changes the cascade nature in determining which declarations are applied. For a great, detailed answer explaining this, see [this answer by BoltClock](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5805204/2680216).

Comment: I tried that. I added specificity to the brown while important and it overwrote the green. So, basically adding a positive specificity is stronger than a negative specificity? In other words, I specified two instructions: a positive one - div.brown...!important and a negative one: - :not.....!important and the brown prevailed

Comment: @LOTUSMS No, it's because of the weight of the total selector. `div:not(.red)` has both an element and a class. `.brown` has only a class.  http://jsfiddle.net/4Zj5C/2/

Comment: a classic: http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html notice how `.whatever` only gets a vader but `a.whatever` gets a stormtrooper and a vader!

Comment: Ah, I see. So ultimately, a total selector that contains both element and id would claim supremacy.