# What is Specificity value of !important in css?

Tags: html, css

What is Specificity value of !important in css?
Like:
100 for each ID, 
10 for each attribute, class or pseudo-class, 
1 for each element name or pseudo-element.

If I used !Important in css then what will be value of Specificity?

Answer (score 2):

MDN's article on [**specificity**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) states about the *!important* rule:

> When an !important rule is used on a style declaration, this declaration overrides any other declaration made in the CSS, wherever it is in the declaration list. **Although, !important has nothing to do with specificity.**

So, it has no specificity value. It just overrides any other rule, regardless of its value combination.

**Now...**

When there's more than one declaration using the *!important* rule, then the specificity value will be the tie breaker.

Answer (score 0):

> Specificity value only applies with selectors. **!important** is
>   considered as declaration so it means there is no specificity value to
>   that.

More info = https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#biblio-css21.

In addition to that. !important discussion is also mentioned here. [Relationship between !important and CSS specificity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805040/relationship-between-important-and-css-specificity/5805116#5805116)