# Text color won't change on LI elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

As you can see on my code, on the left panel, i have an UL and 2 LI.

I want all LI as white color.

I've set style but is not professional, perhaps setting my own style:

lblBiancoMenu does not affect

what can i do?

```css
.lblBiancoMenu {
  color: white;
}

;
.subCat .li {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title>Pushy - Off-Canvas Navigation Menu</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Pushy is an off-canvas navigation menu for your website.">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <!-- Icons list-> https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_comp_glyphs.asp-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>


  <div data-role="page" id="pageone">

    <div style=" background-color: #101010;  color: #ffffff;">
      <h2 id="listCateg">Categories</h2>


      <div id="SubCat3" class='subCat'>
        <ul>
          <li><a style="color:white" href="#">3</a></li>
          <li><a class="lblBiancoMenu" href="#">4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>





  </div>


</body>


</HTML>
```

Answer (score 2):

The theme you're importing has its own CSS styles. The color rule being imported has a higher [specificity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37713015/3597276) than your rule, so your rule is being overridden.

[image]

To override the theme styles, either use inline CSS (as you have done). Embedding the CSS in the HTML tag gives it higher specificity.

Or use the `!important` annotation, which overrides all other CSS declarations.

Use this in your code:

```
.lblBiancoMenu {
  color: white !important;
}
```

```css
.lblBiancoMenu {
  color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title>Pushy - Off-Canvas Navigation Menu</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Pushy is an off-canvas navigation menu for your website.">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <!-- Icons list-> https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_comp_glyphs.asp-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>


  <div data-role="page" id="pageone">

    <div style=" background-color: #101010;  color: #ffffff;">
      <h2 id="listCateg">Categories</h2>


      <div id="SubCat3" class='subCat'>
        <ul>
          <li><a style="color:white" href="#">3</a></li>
          <li><a class="lblBiancoMenu" href="#">4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>





  </div>


</body>


</html>
```