# Changing the order of comma-separated selectors breaks styling

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

If I change the order of elements in a sub selector it affects an element outside of the class.

Common HTML:

```
<input type='text'>
<hr>
<table class="mytable">
  <tbody> 
    <tr><td><input type='text'></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type='text'></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type='text'></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This CSS works ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/andyarvid/hazm9p15/)):

```
input {
  margin: 0 0 2em;
}
table.mytable input,select,a {
  margin: 0;
}
```

The following CSS causes the first input before the table to lose its margin simply by placing `<select>` first in the sublist of elements ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/andyarvid/201856ye)). That is the mytable class is activated (selected) for the first input box when it should not be.

```
input {
  margin: 0 0 2em;
}
table.mytable select,input,a {
  margin: 0;
}
```

I tested this in both Chrome and Firefox and they both act the same way.  So is this a bug? or Can someone explain what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your CSS is written doesn't work in "sub-sets" as you may have hoped.

By placing select first, you've inadvertently now removed the margin from ALL inputs.

The way you have it now, if I were to break it apart would look like this:

```
input {
    margin: 0 0 2em;
}

table.mytable input {
    margin: 0;
}

select {
    margin: 0;
}

a {
    margin: 0;
}
```

To get it to work the way you want, you need to include table.mytable with each of the "subsets" you want after each comma.

```
input {
     margin: 0 0 2em;
}

table.mytable select,
table.mytable input,
table.mytable a {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The first selector:

```
table.mytable input, select, a
```

targets the following elements:

- inputs that are descendants of `table.mytable`
- all `select` elements
- all anchor elements

`table.mytable input` uses a [*descendant combinator*](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#descendant-combinators) (the space) to structure the table / input relationship. It applies `margin: 0` only to those particular inputs.

Your second selector:

```
table.mytable select, input, a
```

applies `margin: 0` to these elements:

- `select` elements that are descendants of `table.mytable`
- all `input` elements
- all anchor elements

So, your first selector targets a particular group of inputs, while the second selector targets *all* inputs.

In the [first example](https://jsfiddle.net/andyarvid/hazm9p15/), the first input rule targets all inputs. But the second input rule overrides the first rule due to [*higher specificity*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35657646/3597276). The first rule ends up matching all inputs, except those targeted by the second rule.

In the [second example](https://jsfiddle.net/andyarvid/201856ye/), the first and second input rules are targeting the same group (all inputs) and have the same weight in terms of specificity. The second rule wins because [*it is processed later in the cascade*](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/cascade.html#cascading-order). Because both rules are targeting the same group, the first rule is overridden, thus causing the problem you're having.

To target only the inputs within the table try this:

```
table.mytable select, 
table.mytable input,
a
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```css
input {
  margin: 0 0 2em;
}
table.mytable select, table.mytable input, table.mytable a {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type='text'>
<hr>
<table class="mytable">
  <tbody> 
    <tr><td><input type='text'></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type='text'></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type='text'></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```