# Target an element when not inside another element (i.e., all anchors not inside paragraphs)

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to style all `a` tags that are not inside of a `p` tag. Here's what I'm thinking:

```css
p {
  font-size: 1.25rem
}
a {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
:not(p) a {
  font-size: .75rem;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>There is a <a>link</a> inside this paragraph</p>
  <a>Regular Link</a>
</div>
```

How can I fix this? Can you not use the `:not()` selector without a tag in front of it? (*no js/jQuery solutions please*)

**[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mcfaLL42/)**

Comment: Why use `:not()` at all, when you can simply use: `a { font-size: .75rem; } p a { font-size: inherit; }`?

Comment: The first a is still child of the grandparent `div` element ... you may need to check for direct descendants with `>` https://jsfiddle.net/mcfaLL42/2/

Comment: @DaniP: nice catch! CSS Apprentice: had you included your relevant code in your question you could have been helped a great deal faster.

Comment: @DaniP - Why didn't `:not(p) a` work though, and yet `:not(p) > a" does? Doesn't the first solution still have better specificity? That's more of what I was looking for though, thanks a ton!

@DavidThomas - Sorry about that, didn't think about how relevant it was at the time.

Comment: @DavidThomas - Oh, and I mentioned the reason in a comment to Michael_B. My reasoning: *"going the `:not(p)` route would keep me from having to write `inherit` inside `p a` for all the styles that I declare in a `p` tag and thus would ideally be more efficient concerning file size. That's why I was hoping to use the other technique above a direct declaration."*

Comment: Your selector will match any `a` tag inside a container that isn't a **p** tag ... your first  a tag is child of p but also child of div or body tags so it is selected too.... with the `>` you skip the deepest levels so if it will target only the a tags that are direct childs of non p containers

Answer (score 1):

Why not style all `a` tags, then apply different styles to all `a` tags inside `p` tags?

```css
p {
  font-size: 1.25rem
}
a {                             /* 1 */
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-size: .75em;
}
p a {                           /* 2 */
  color: green;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>There is a <a>link</a> inside this paragraph</p>
  <a>Regular Link</a>
</div>
```

Notes:

1. This selector targets all anchor tags in the document
2. This selector overrides the first selector due to [higher specificity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35657646/3597276), targeting only anchor tags in paragraph elements.

Comment: This is definitely a valid option, but going the `:not(p)` route would keep me from having to write `inherit` inside `p a` for all the styles that I declare in a `p` tag and thus would ideally be more efficient concerning file size. That's why I was hoping to use the other technique above a direct declaration.

Comment: CSS Selectors 3 doesn't provide for [parent selectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector). An alternative is JS/jQuery. Or you can wait for the `:has()` pseudo-class coming in [Selectors 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#relational).

Comment: Oh wow, `:has()` will open up a TON of new options! Exciting times, thanks for sharing that!

Answer (score 0):

just use this for `a` inside the `p`:

```
p a {
//*Your style there*/
}
```

and this for `a` outside `p`

```
a {
//*Your style there*/
}
```