# Is a sticky header possible in AMP?

Tags: javascript, css, amp-html

So far I haven't found a solid way to create a sticky header on AMP pages. I know there are CSS workaround/hacks, but nothing I can use in a production environment. A simple "position:fixed;" unfortunately won't work in my case.

Out of all the components, I thought there would be one that toggles a body class on scroll, but I haven't found anything yet. Also don't think "amp-position-observer" will be of any use.

Am I missing something? Ideally I'd like to be able to toggle an element's class name after a scroll of X amount of pixels. Is this possible in AMP?

Comment: Why doesn't `position: fixed` work? There's an official example of just that: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/examples/article-fixed-header.amp.html

Comment: have you tried position:sticky? (here's a good blog on it https://gedd.ski/post/position-sticky/)

Comment: @ceejayoz due to the nature of the header, I can't keep the same layout on scroll. There are some sub items that need to disappear, background color needs to change etc. Might have to go that route and deal with the design sacrifice. No biggie.

Comment: @RachelGallen I'm thinking it will be the same issue as above. If there was some sort of pseudo selector, I could do it. .header:sticky {background-color:red}
Unfortunately, no dice.

Comment: @JosephWer is there a reason why you are looking  for css attributes? You could easily use the scrollTop position in a js function to update a classname after a certain amount of pixels..

Comment: @RachelGallen this is a Google AMP project, so unfortunately no custom javascript is allowed :(

Answer (score 6):

Toggling an element's classname after a scroll of X amount of pixels is currently not supported as amp-position-observer [does not allow changing amp-state](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-position-observer#what-can-i-do-with-amp-position-observer?).

You can combine amp-position-observer to change parts of the header using amp-animation. However, it's application is limited as the [supported CSS properties are limited](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-animation#white-listed-properties-for-keyframes). Nevertheless, with a little bit of creativity this approach can be quite flexible. One possible pattern is to duplicate elements in your header which are then shown/hidden based on your scrolling position.

[Here](https://amp-demos.glitch.me/sticky-header.html) is a sample highlighting the header based on the currently focused section.

Answer (score 1):

I built a working solution of a sticky header within an amp-list. The pitfall is that amp elements add `display: block` and `position: absolute` on many elements.

To use **`position: sticky`** you need to use **`display: inline`** and **`position: relative`** on all subelements on your header. Make sure these are actually applied and not overwritten, use id to get a higher [specificity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35657410/how-do-i-give-a-css-class-priority-over-an-id) over the amp css classes.

Here's an example using an amp list
css:

- All divs need **`display: inline`**
- The amp-list gets an **id** (not class) to apply css to itself and the generated child div
- Divs can be nested as long as they use `display: inline`

```css
.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  background-color:white;
  top: 40px;
}

.inline {
  display: inline;
}

#list-wrapper, #list-wrapper>div {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <amp-list [src]="..." items="." single-item layout="flex-item" id="list-wrapper">
        <template type="amp-mustache">
            <div class="inline">
                <span class="sticky">
                    <span>Sticky header</span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </template>
    </amp-list>
    <div>Your content</div>
<div>
```