# Make fixed header that is amp-html compliant

Tags: css, amp-html

The amp-validator disallows using `position: fixed` in style sheets.

Is there another way to make a header that is attached to the top and does not scroll in an amp-conform way?

EDIT:

Full example:

```
<div style="background:red;position:fixed;right:-50px;padding-left:50px;padding-right:50px;transform:translateY(100%) rotate(45deg)">
    <h5>Text</h5>
</div>
```

Here is the error message I am getting:

```
[ warn ]  Amp Validation

/  error  CSS syntax error in tag 'div' - the property 'position' is set to the disallowed value 'fixed'.  https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/develop/style_and_layout/style_pages
```

Comment: position:sticky ?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus also banned

Comment: okay :( , did you see that one ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50827468/google-amp-sticky-header-possible demo here https://amp-demos.glitch.me/sticky-header.html validates at https://validator.ampproject.org/#url=https%3A%2F%2Famp-demos.glitch.me%2Fsticky-header.html

Comment: That's weird. I tried both sticky/fixed and validation failed locally. Also, check https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/validator/validator-main.protoascii line 3106 " # CSS property `position` with values `fixed` and `sticky are not allowed."

Comment: funny, for me : https://validator.ampproject.org/#url=https%3A%2F%2Famp-demos.glitch.me%2Fsticky-header.html it says it is passing the test ? file probably out of date from  From https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Comment: Paste `<div style="background:red;position:fixed;right:-50px;padding-left:50px;padding-right:50px;transform:translateY(100%) rotate(45deg)">` after `<body>` in your link will make it fail. I assume it works for non-inline styles???

Comment: I would trust the official online validator ;) ah i see, you mean validator being tricked ?

Comment: Yes, it works if I extract "position:fixed" from the inline style into a global style sheet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for https://stackoverflow.com/users/2442099/g-cyrillus to point out the solution:

The validation fails if `position: fixed` is used as inline style.

Using

```
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
}
```

and

```
<div class="fixed" style="background:red;right:-50px;padding-left:50px;padding-right:50px;transform:translateY(100%) rotate(45deg)">
```

the amp-validator can be convinced.