# CSS Specificity - Internal vs inline vs external style

Tags: css

I know that inline has more specificity than external but does internal have more than inline? Or is it the other way around?

Internal:

```
<style>
p{
  color: red;
}
</style>
```

Inline:

```
<p style="color:blue">
```

External:

```
p{
  color:green;
}
```

Comment: That would depend entirely on the order of the CSS loading.  For equal CSS styles, whichever is loaded last will take precedent

Comment: https://www.hungred.com/useful-information/inline-internal-external-css-style-print/
--OR--
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp 
at the end of the page

Comment: Specificity is determined by an algorithm, detailed in [Selectors Level 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#specificity).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding CSS selector priority / specificity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072365/understanding-css-selector-priority-specificity)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, internal does not take over inline. Inline styles are always the highest priority. From [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity):

> Inline styles added to an element (e.g., `style="font-weight: bold;"`) always overwrite any styles in external stylesheets, and thus can be thought of as having the highest specificity.

These "external stylesheets" also include `style` tags in the `head` or `body`. See for yourself:

```css
p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<style>
  p {
    color: red;
  }
</style>

<p style="color: blue">
  Hello!
</p>

<style>
  p {
    color: red;
  }
</style>
```

Whether it is **before or after**, the only thing that will override an inline style is `!important`, which you should shy away from using. Refer to the MDN link above.

---

Finally, be careful when you say,

> I know that Inline has more specificity than external [...]

since *specificity* is a special CSS concept. Yes, inline styles will override external styles (when not using `!important`), but don't confuse *specificity* with precedence. CSS rules are ranked in two ways:

1. Specificity
2. and Order.

This includes order across separate files. If you put your `style` tag before your `link` tag, then the external styles will overwrite the internal ones (if they are of the same specificity).

Again, this doesn't apply much to internal styles, and this is mostly a semantics clarification for "specificity," but it doesn't hurt to point out.

Comment: This question about `!important` is worth reading too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805040/relationship-between-important-and-css-specificity