# !important isn't working : style inherits from specific selector instead

Tags: css

I stumbed upon this case. **I'm not trying to resolve it**, I just want to understand the cause.

I have this HTML (I cannot change the HTML in this project) :

```
<span class="cat-title title">
  <h2>
    <span>
      Partie membre
    </span>
  </h2>
</span>
```

And this CSS :

```
.cat-title h2 span {
  font-size: 11px;
}

.cat-title h2 {
  font-size: 50pt !important;
}
```

**What I'm expecting :**
The text should be 50pt since I used `!important`, not 11px.

**The result I'm getting :**
The text is 11px.

I thought it was because `.cat-title h2 span` was more specific, but I don't think it makes sense : `!important` is meant to rule over all the other CSS rules.

Why is that ? What is the reason behind that ?

Thank you !

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805040/relationship-between-important-and-css-specificity

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178673/how-to-override-important?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you inspect the page, you can see that the style `font-size: 50pt !important;` is being applied to the `h2`, just like it says in the stylesheet. But the `h2` has no text, it only contains a span. The span can inherit text styles from its parent, but these inherited styles are not the highest specificity for the child elements that inherit them, even though you used `!important`.

Answer (score 1):

```
.cat-title h2 span {
  font-size: 11px;

}
```

this targets the  tag inside of h2 whereas,

```
.cat-title h2 {
  font-size: 50pt !important;
/* if you want span of 50pt uncomment below line*/
  /* font-size: 50pt; */
}
```

this targets the h2

Given your code, if you modify it as shown then HIII will be of size 50pt:

```
<h2>
     HIIII
    <span>
      Partie membre
    </span>
  </h2>
```

Comment: Thank you ! But I was searching for the reason why it was working this way. Raphael Serota answered to the question, but thanks !