# Error with jQuery syntax?

Tags: jquery, css

Based on an answer from the stack overflow post at: [Change background color on mouseover and remove it after mouseout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741157/change-background-color-on-mouseover-and-remove-it-after-mouseout)

the below code should set the css to display: block; on hover and display: none; when they hover off.

Can anyone see anything wrong with the below code? (No console errors are occuring) I'm basically trying to make myself a simple tool tip.

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('hover', '.inter [class]', function () {
        $('._22t').css({
            'display': 'block'
        });
    }, function () {
        $('._22t').css({
            'display': 'none'
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: `on()` only takes one function argument, not two. Read the documentation.

Comment: maybe you should try `$('._22t').toggleClass('your_css_class');`

Comment: So simply changing it to $('.inter [class]').hover() would fix it?

Comment: That will work if all the elements exist at the time you run it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`on` doesn't accept 2 callback functions and apart from that you can't use `hover` pseudo event name with the `on` method:

> *Deprecated in jQuery 1.8, removed in 1.9:* The name "hover" used as a shorthand for the string `"mouseenter mouseleave"`. It attaches a single event handler for those two events, and the handler must examine `event.type` to determine whether the event is `mouseenter` or `mouseleave`. Do not confuse the "hover" pseudo-event-name with the `.hover()` method, which accepts one or two functions.

```
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.inter [class]', function(event) {
    $('._22t').toggle(event.type === 'mouseenter');
});
```